# Stuck in CodeWars question.. Persistent Bugger problem

Tags: persistence

> I tried solving CodeWars problem today and problem instructions was:
>   [image]
>
> and my code trying to solve this problem was:

```
def persistence(n):

count = 0
multi = 1

while n > 9:
    string = str(n)
    for i in string:
        operator = int(i)
        multi *= operator
    count += 1
    n = multi

return count
```

> And it passed sample tests of  persistence(4) = 0, persistence(25) =
>   2, persistence(999) = 4, but could not pass this one sample: 
>   persistence(39) = 3, my code gives me 4 instead of 3.   I could not
>   figure out what was going on with sample input 39.  Could anyone
>   explain any error to my code please?

Answer (score 0):

As I could not see it at first sight either, I ran your code in `pythontutor.com`.
The only piece missing in your code is resetting to 1 your "multi" variable at the end of the while loop.

```python
    def persistence(n):
        count = 0
        multi = 1

        while n > 9:
            string = str(n)
            for i in string:
                operator = int(i)
                multi *= operator
            count += 1
            n = multi
            multi = 1

        return count
```